Until vs before with continuous tenses

I won't  go there until the trains are running again

I won't go there before the trains are running again


Can you explain the difference between "until" and "before"? To me they are quite similiar. Yet, 1 is correct but 2 with continuous is wrong. Why?

Who said 'before' is wrong?

I was told by teachera that we don't use past continuous after "before".

Passengers are advised to NOT attempt to travel before the trains are running normally again. Transport for Wales advice to travellers.

@MichaelHarvey  Is is also possible with "after"? "I will travel to you after the trains are running normally again and after the trains runs normally again". Both here with the same meaing?

When the trains are running normally would be more usual. You could use after, but not after the trains run normally (it means the same but isn't idiomatic).

@KateBunting I'm a little puzzled. I used to think the continuous tenses aren't used with "after" or "before". Could you tell what would  be the difference for instsance here? 1 "I will give you water after you run". So, once I have finished running I get water, correct? 2"I will give you water after you are running" once you are in the middle of running you get water?

The difference is that 'trains running normally' is a continuing situation, while a person going for a run is not - they will run for a certain time/distance and then stop.  (Note that I used run as a noun, which would be more idiomatic - "I'll give you some water after your run".)

@KateBunting Could I use "by the time" instead of "before"? "Passengers are advised to NOT attempt to travel by the time the trains are running normally again."

No! By the time implies the end of a period of waiting, if I make myself clear. "The letter still hadn't arrived by the time I had to leave home", or "By the time she came downstairs the rest of us had finished our breakfast".

@Kate Bunting So it isn't about the continuous tense. Passengers are advised to NOT attempt to travel by the time the trains run normally again is also wrong, yes?

No, it isn't about the tense; by the time isn't idiomatic in that context.

@KateBunting  Could you give one more example because I'm not sure if I really see the difference between "before" and "by the time"?

I'm finding it really difficult to explain clearly. By the time is used when, at the time some event happened, either something else that you were waiting for hadn't yet happened or an action had already finished.  Your sentence is about not being allowed to do something (travel by train) until something else happens (normal service starts).


won't X until Y

often suggests that you will do X after Y happens. Not necessarily immediately after, but Y addresses a reason why you're not doing X. In your example, you can only go there using a train.

won't X before Y

doesn't have that same implication. It simply describes what you're doing, or not doing, earlier. You wouldn't ordinarily use this phrasing for something that will change due to Y. A more common use would be something like

I won't eat any snacks before dinnertime.

Conversely, you wouldn't say:

I won't eat any snacks until dinnertime.

That implies you'll eat a snack when dinnertime arrives, which is unlikely (you'll presumably eat dinner then, not a snack). But you could say:

I won't eat any food until dinnertime.

